# SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, twitter, compiler-errors, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to get a sentimental score for live tweets using Stanford Core NLP. Currently I'm getting the real-time tweets. But when I feed it to the Stanford Core NLP program i'm getting an error.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class NLP {
    static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public static void init() {
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP("MyPropFile.properties");
    }

    public static int findSentiment(String tweet) {

        int mainSentiment = 0;
        if (tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0) {
            int longest = 0;
            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(tweet);
            for (CoreMap sentence : annotation
                    .get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                Tree tree = sentence
                        .get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
                int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
                String partText = sentence.toString();
                if (partText.length() > longest) {
                    mainSentiment = sentiment;
                    longest = partText.length();
                }

            }
        }
        return mainSentiment;
    }
}
```

I'm calling to this init() and findSentiment() functions from outside the class NLP.

```
NLP.init();
System.out.println(status.getText() + " : " + NLP.findSentiment(status.getText()));
```

My error is: **SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree cannot be resolved to a type**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
```

to

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
```